# Python compare 2 lists with duplicates

Tags: python, list

I want to compare 2 lists and return the matches in a list. But when I do this I don't get the matches that are identical.

```
    matches = []
    l1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    l2 = [2, 4, 4]
    for n in l2:
        if n in l1:
        matches.append(n)
        print(matches)
```

this returns:

```
   [2, 4]
```

and what I would like it to return is:

```
   [2, 4, 4]
```

Comment: What is the expected output for this:
l1 = [2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5] and
l2 = [2, 4, 4, 5]

Answer (score 2):

This actually works, you just missed the indent.

```
matches = []
l1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l2 = [2, 4, 4]
for n in l2:
    if n in l1:
        matches.append(n)
print(matches)
```

Output: `[2, 4, 4]`

Comment: Dear Poalo, Thanks alot I saw it indeed the main code I worked I made the mistake of comparing first from l1 instead of l2. But with writing this out and your first comment I now see the logic! Thank you kind sir :D

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a **[list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**:

```
>>> l1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> l2 = [2, 4, 4]
>>> l1_set = set(l1)  # Convert to set for O(1) lookup time.
>>> matches = [n for n in l2 if n in l1_set]
>>> matches
[2, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Dear Sash, thanks for your reply! This would indeed be a more compact end cleaner practise. But I don't undestand what the reason for using the 'set' operator in front of l1? Would you care to explain?

Comment: The lookup time for a list is O(N), i.e., the whole list needs to be traversed, while the lookup time on a set is O(1), i.e., it is constant time.

Comment: Dear Sash, thanks for your explanation it makes sense to me now. Again thanks for your time and effort in this!

Answer (score 0):

Python mainly depends on the indentation and hence it becomes very important to indent a code to get the required output

The correct code is :

```
matches = []
l1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l2 = [2, 4, 4]
for n in l2:
    if n in l1:
        matches.append(n)
print(matches)
```

We get : [2,4,4]